# Get client ip TCP net node

Tags: node.js, sockets, typescript, tcp

I have this net TCP server:

```
private startTCPServer() {
    const socket = net.createServer(function(socket_object){
        socket_object.on("data", (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        });
        socket_object.on("end", socket_object.end);
        socket_object.on("error", (err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
    socket.listen(this.TCP_PORT, this.ADDRESS, () => {
        console.log('listening...');
    });
}
```

How can I get the ip of clients that connects to this server mainly when the reach the `"data"` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [`connectListener`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_connection) (the function given to `createServer`) gets the `socket_object` which is an object of type [`net.Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket). There is a property `remoteAddress` which has the address of the remote host.

Comment: This remote address changes on each reconnection so that is a bit complicated !

Comment: @AstritSpanca Yes, if a different system connects the address will be different. What is the complicated thing here?

Comment: No the answer is simple but managing can be complicated since on each reconnection device comes with a different remote address